# Scraping some specified part of url content

Tags: php, python, web-scraping

I am using [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [pyquery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)(on python) and [pquery](https://github.com/tburry/pquery) (on php) to scraping(parse and fetch my desire part of html of url), But I have one problem with them, the number of  URLs I want to try to fetch them is too much and all of this methods first try to load all section of page the we can scrap it with desire selectors,I just need some part of that pages , as example only specified class but I must get all of the page, I cause more consumption on bandwidth.

**I want to know is there any way ( my knowledge tells me there is not but I ask maybe someone has idea or trick about it) or tools that instead get all page only try to get specified part of it?**

**more deatils:**

let suppose I want get my answer title in this page,  the url is https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34892845
and I just want text of `question-hyperlink`. I want get the title without get the whole of the page data ( I don't want fetch the whole of the page because saving my bandwidth in bulk operation)

Comment: did you tried any other scrapping method like CURL

Comment: yes I did, but I want don't fetch all data of url first?  I want prevent band-width consumtion

Comment: Take a look at `CURLOPT_RANGE` although your specifying the range of the page to grab in KB and page sizes can vary.

Comment: @Matt `http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RANGE.html` it is based on byte not specified class, I want to get data of specified element with specified class .

Comment: Oh, my mistake, it is bytes sorry. There is no way to just download a specific class. The best you can do would be to load X amount until you have found the specified class.

Comment: @Matt tnx, I know that there is no way,just ask here to maybe somebody know a trick or  a tools( or service) to do it